# Tab separated file with file names in first column and path in the second column

Tags: linux, sed, tabs, printf

I'm new to linux and I need to find a way to have a tab delimited file that read files in a directory and put a first column with names and a second column with the path like:

xxx ---> /PATH/xxx.fasta

I have found the script bellow that partially do the job but it can also add the path to the first column which I don't want to.
Can somebody help me please.
Thank you in advance

```
paste -d '\t' \
    <(printf "%s\n" PATH/*.fasta | sort) \
    | sed 's/\(.*\).fasta/\1\t\1.fasta/' \
    > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in PATH/*.fasta; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(basename "$f" .fasta)" "$f"
done > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` and `sed` can do this for you:

```bash
find /PATH/*.fasta | sed -E 's#((/[^/]+)*/([^/]+)\.[^.]+)$#\3\t\1#' > out.txt
```